# What is the difference between (click) and (ngSubmit) in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In submitting a form in Angular 2 I have gotten two patterns to work.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="pathSave()" #fDoc="ngForm">
  ( bunch of form fields ) 
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

versus

```html
<form #fDoc="ngForm">
  ( bunch of form fields ) 
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="pathSave()">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The difference being where the Component's action method is called.  Is there an advantage of one pattern over the other?

Comment: well, i mean, one is a click event, the other is a submit event. one gets called before the other, and one gets called by more actions than just clicking the submit button while the other only responds to click.

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote.  It seems like a legitimate question with practical application and fills a documentation hole at least as far as I have seen.  What gives?

Comment: I have the same question, and I think it's not really answered yet. In the result yes it is the same thing but in other terms ? code optimization ? maintenance ? speed ? something else ? there must be a recommended way

Comment: @walox I think that Günter Zöchbauer answered the question well enough, given my original typo in the question.   End result is there is no practical difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `(onclick)` event, only `(click)`.

The difference is that `(ngSubmit)` listens to the `ngSubmit` event of the `NgForm` directive and `click` to the click event of the `<button>` element.

The button in the 2nd example will cause the `submit` event which also causes the `ngSubmit` event, but because it is not listened to, it will have no effect.

In your examples there is no difference in the behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is relatively old and already has an accepted answer, I want to give additional information for people who might come across this post in the future:

As [Günter Zöchbauer wrote in his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43899041), there is no difference in behaviour between the two approaches. Although this is only true, if just viewed from the point of 'will the click lead to my function being called'.

I want to link this excellent blog post by Wojciech Trawiński: [Form submission — why it’s crucial to use a button of submit type](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/form-submission-why-its-crucial-to-use-a-button-of-submit-type-b43511d92671) that I stumbled upon while researching this topic, because it gives some very good reasons as to why one should choose the submit route over the click event. The idea being, that submit exists for a reason and has both, HTML and Angular behaviour 'attached' to it, which would all be thrown out the window if one chooses the use a regular click event (or really any other event).